# Need help on tamil character counting using PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
<?php
$str = "இந்தியர்களின்";
echo strlen($str);
echo "<br>".mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');?>
```

Which outputs
39
13

But as you seen in code only 8 characters are there (I accept 13 is the correct one by logic). But I need the character count only.

Can anyone provide me the solution for this

Comment: This code works fine! I just copied it in Notpad++ and this string are 13 characters long! This `இந்தியர்களின்` === `இ ந ் த ி ய ர ் க ள ி ன ்`

Comment: @Rizier123 But the string is 8 charchters long so what is your point.

Comment: @Jordy No you see only 8 but there are 13

Comment: Looks like this: http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries

Comment: Can you try grapheme_strlen() as well? My guess is 13 unicode code points, 8 grapheme clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
<?php
$str = "இந்தியர்களின்";
   echo grapheme_strlen($str);
?>
```

This works as expected

Thanks